# Perform calculations in orgtbl with the LaTeX syntax?

Tags: latex, org-table, orgtbl

This is an `orgtbl` table

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results none
(setq calc-language 'latex)
(calc-radians-mode)
#+end_src

#+attr_latex: :mode math 
|----------+-----+----------|
| Fonction | var | Dérivée  |
|----------+-----+----------|
| cos(x)   | x   | -\sin(x) |
| \cos(x)  | x   | #ERROR   |
|----------+-----+----------|
#+TBLFM: $3=deriv($1,$2);RL
```

I would like orgmode to display \cos(x) on the @2 line when I Input cos(x).
If I input \cos(x) on the @3 line, the formula deriv($1,$2) gives an error.
How can I obtain the correct LaTeX syntax for the input and the output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the setting `latex` for `calc-language` to `org-calc-default-modes`.

The following example Org file shows how you can do that with file-local variables:

```
|----------+-----+----------+----------|
| Fonction | var | Dérivée  |          |
|----------+-----+----------+----------|
| cos(x)   | x   | -\sin{x} | -\cos{x} |
| \cos(x)  | x   | -\sin{x} | -\cos{x} |
|----------+-----+----------+----------|
#+TBLFM: $3=deriv($1,$2);RL


* Local Variables :noexport:

Local Variables:
eval: (plist-put org-calc-default-modes 'calc-language 'latex)
End:
```

You must reopen the file for the setting to take effect.

---

Alternatively, you can add the following code to your init file.

With that code you can add comma-separated Calc settings to the modes of a table formula. The first setting must be a mode as described in the Org manual. The subsequent settings have the form `VARIABLE:VALUE` where `VARIABLE` is the Calc variable such as `calc-language` and `VALUE` is the value for this variable such as `latex`. Below the code there is an example Org table with such setting.

```el
(defun org+-top-level-split-string (equation &optional separators table)
  "Split string EQUATION at top-level SEPARTORS.
SEPARATORS is a regexp.
EQUATION can be an org table equation as used for `org-table-eval-formula'.
In that the default value [;,] for SEPARATORS is appropriate."
  (unless separators
    (setq separators "[;,]"))
  (unless table
    (setq table org-mode-syntax-table))
  (let (ret
    (pos 1))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (with-syntax-table table
    (insert equation)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (null (eobp))
      (when (looking-at separators)
        (setq ret (cons (buffer-substring-no-properties pos (point))
                ret)
          pos (goto-char (match-end 0))))
      (forward-sexp))
    (when (> (point) pos)
      (setq ret (cons (buffer-substring-no-properties pos (point)) ret)))))
    (nreverse ret)))
;; Test: (org+-table-formula-mode-split "deriv($1,$2);RL,calc-language:latex")

(defvar org-calc-default-modes) ;; defined in org-table.el
(declare-function org-table-eval-formula "org-table")
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'subr-x))

(defun org+-table-eval-formula-mode (fun arg equation &rest rest)
  "Allow direct settings for `org-calc-default-modes'.
These settings are given in the formula as comma separated list.
Each setting has the form VARIABLE:VALUE where VARIABLE is one of
Calc's variable names and VALUE is the value in `read' syntax."
  (let* ((org-calc-default-modes (seq-copy org-calc-default-modes))
     (eq-flags (org+-top-level-split-string equation))
     (eq (car eq-flags))
     (modes (cadr eq-flags))
     (settings (cddr eq-flags)))
    (when (stringp modes)
      (setq eq (concat eq ";" modes)))
    (dolist (setting settings)
      (when-let ((pos (cl-position ?: setting))
         (var (intern-soft (substring setting 0 pos)))
         (val (read (substring setting (1+ pos)))))
    (setq org-calc-default-modes
          (nconc (list var val)
             org-calc-default-modes))))
    (apply fun arg eq rest)))

(advice-add 'org-table-eval-formula :around #'org+-table-eval-formula-mode)
```

The example org table:

```
|----------+-----+----------+----------|
| Fonction | var | Dérivée  |          |
|----------+-----+----------+----------|
| cos(x)   | x   | -\sin{x} | -\cos{x} |
| \cos(x)  | x   | -\sin{x} | -\cos{x} |
|----------+-----+----------+----------|
#+TBLFM: $3=deriv($1,$2);RL,calc-language:latex
```